# jquery scrollToFixed limit within multiple DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I've been trying to solve this for the last 48 hours and I really can't find a solution. I'm using https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed plugin and I want to limit the fixed position within a parent DIV. I did see **all** the related questions about scrollToFixed in stackoverflow and the project github page, but I didn't find any clue for solving this.

So far, I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/CVMjp/1/

This is the basic HTML structure:

```
<div class="container" id="element_1">
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
</div>
```

And this would be my jQuery function to affect each element on page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
for (i = 1; i <= $('.sticky').length; i++) {

    $('#element_' + i + ' .sticky').scrollToFixed({
        marginTop: 20, 
                  zIndex:1,
                  limit: $('#element_' + (i + 1) + ' .content').offset().top - $('#element_' + i + ' .sticky').height() - 50
    });
}       
});
```

**I want the .sticky box to stay at the bottom of each .content when it reaches the bottom.** Right now in my example, when it reaches the bottom of the .content DIV, it changes its "fixed" position to "absolute", but there are problems with the body margin (because it has the "left" position based on the body rather than the left position within the .content) and other issues I can't really find the source of the problem.

Also, in the jsfiddle example there is no problem with the **$(document).ready**, but in my online site I had to use **$(window).load** to get the right **offset().top** of each .content DIV. When I use document.ready, apparently all the .content DIVs are treated like they all have the same height, although they are different because they have different amount of content inside.

I will be updating this question if I can solve this, but I could use some help.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a little bit different approach.

First `.sticky` should be in a container. Then make the layout table like with `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. `table-layout: fixed` will help you keep both `.sidebar` and `.content` of the same height.
Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJJhX/), Sir.

There're limitations however. For example, you can you use `position: relative` on your body tag only.

Concerning the `offset().top` issue you may use [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) plugin and apply it to your `.content` only. Don't know of better solutions though.